# how to run a console script in the background

Tags: php, exec, nohup

In my controller I am doing:

> shell_exec('nohup /var/www/html/terminal/yii socket/run > nohup.txt 2>&1 &');

But nohup doesn't work if I run:

> shell_exec('/var/www/html/terminal/yii socket/run');

The script runs but the page is loading and hangs.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the space in the directory, try this

```
shell_exec('"nohup /var/www/html/terminal/yii socket/run > nohup.txt 2>&1 &"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `absolute path` for nohup command

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/nohup /var/www/html/terminal/yii socket/run > nohup.txt 2>&1 &');
```

hope it helps :)